# Get aspx Page reference in another class or class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, performance

For example, I have this method in the `Link.cs` class for easy URL mapping of the `Global.asax` routes:

```
public static string ToCategory(string categoryName, ushort pageNumber, Page page)
{
    if (pageNumber == 1)
        return page.GetRouteUrl("category", new { CategoryName = categoryName });
    else
        return page.GetRouteUrl("category-page", new { CategoryName = categoryName, Page = pageNumber });
}
```

The `GetRouteUrl()` method is part of the `Page` class, but I pass the object as value, so in theory it copy the whole thing and use more memory than pass just the reference... or I'm wrong? Is there any performace overhead in doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects (aka reference-type parameters) passed as method parameters are always passed as references to the original object and will not use additional memory.

Note that this is a different concept than passing an object as `ref`, which is essentially a pointer to the objects memory location, which can be modified by the method (for example, creating a new class and assigning it to the parameter).

On the other hand, primitive data types (ints, for example) are passed by value, by default, so will consume additional memory.

[This MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) contains more detailed discussion and examples.